# How to make a table with more columns in a top row than in others?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I am trying to build a simple table in HTML and I came across a problem I can't solve. My table currently looks like this:

[image: My current table]

How can I make it look like this?

[image: Table layout that I want to achieve]

The cell in the second row starts at the half of the top cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try flexbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/87swa6mm/1/

```
<style>
.box {
   background-color: #eee;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
}
.flex-c {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>


<div class="flex-c">
<div class="box">foo</div>
<div class="box">foo</div>
<div class="box">foo</div>
<div class="box">foo</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-c">
<div class="box">foo</div>
<div class="box">foo</div>
<div class="box">foo</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-c">
<div class="box">foo</div>
<div class="box">foo</div>
<div class="box">foo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) Do you maybe know how to fix "double" thickness where two lines stick together? You can see here what I am talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/87swa6mm/2/

Answer (score 0):

two tables...

```html
<table border="1" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table><table border="1" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using twice as many columns as you want visible, then using `colspan="2"`:

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="border" colspan="2">test</td>
    <td class="border" colspan="2">test</td>
    <td class="border" colspan="2">test</td>
    <td class="border" colspan="2">test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="border" colspan="2">test</td>
    <td class="border" colspan="2">test</td>
    <td class="border" colspan="2">test</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```